# Android - Figure Out Small, Normal, Large, XLarge Screen Sizes

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I almost ready to submit my Android app to the store, but I want to start testing on all device sizes before I do so. One method that I think will be effective is if I test my app on the smallest device possible for each category: small, normal, large, and extra-large.

I want to create a new Android emulator for each of these, but when I get to the part where I have to fill out the screen size in inches and the resolution in pixels, I get confused.

How do I figure out what measurements to put in so I can make sure that I create emulators that are the smallest possible screen sizes for their respective categories?

Answer (score 0):

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

The information is taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Check the **Range of screens supported** section. Please, note that the sizes are calculated in **dp**

Comment: So it doesn't matter about the inches I assign to the emulator? As long as I convert the dp into pixels and make an emulator with that resolution, should I be fine?